# Creating a symbolic link for Firefox and launching creates 2 Firefox windows

Tags: linux, firefox, arch-linux, symbolic-link, lxde

I am using Arch Linux and LXDE.

I have downloaded Firefox and moved it over to: `/opt/firefox` (e.g., `mv firefox /opt/firefox`).

Next, I created symbolic link to the user/bin folder:
`ln -s /opt/firefox/firefox /usr/bin/firefox`

When I type in 'firefox' in terminal it launches 2 Firefox windows instead of just one?

Can someone shed some light on why this is happening?

**EDIT:** Deleted my firefox folder in /opt and symbolic link in /usr/bin and reinstalled with `pacman -S firefox` and it still launches 2 windows.

Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: What's your PATH variable show? Also why didn't you just use `pacman -S firefox`?

Comment: How do I show the path variable? Does `pacman -S firefox` download the 64bit version or just the standard 32bit? `echo $PATH` shows me `/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/bin/site_perl:/usr/bin/vendor_perl:/usr/bin/core_perl
`

Comment: Your `$PATH` variable is what I meant, sorry, you showed it though :) Doesn't show any 'odd' signs so it might be a misconfiguration elsewhere (LXDE maybe?) .. but `pacman` will download whatever build you're on, so if your using a 64 bit kernel, it will download the 64 bit version.

Comment: Ok, I just deleted my firefox folder in /opt and the symbolic link in /usr/bin. Installed it with `pacman -S firefox` and it still launches 2 windows.

Answer (score 0):

I just reset Firefox and removed all settings in about:config and extensions, it seems to be back to normal now.